# Roots of a polynomial inside the unit circle

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Let $k$ be a even positive integer. Now, consider the polynomial 
$$
p(x)=x^k-px^{k-1}-qx^{k-2}-x^{k-3}-\cdots -x-1,
$$
with $p$ and $q$ integers satisfying $q-1>p\geq 1$.

How to prove that this polynomial has k-2 roots inside the unit circle (there are two roots outside this circle by using the Descarte sign rule and the intermediate value theorem).

Any suggestion? I tried to use Rouché theorem, but without success.